# How to send post build notification to more than one recepient in a Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm setting up a Jenkins pipeline wherein I want to send post build notification to more than one receipents. i'm not able to find how to set "CC", Can someone help.

An example of my pipeline is as under:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('No-op') {
            steps {
                sh 'ls'
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        failure {
        mail to: 'team@example.com',
             subject: "Failed Pipeline: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}",
             body: "Something is wrong with ${env.BUILD_URL}"
    }
}
```

}

The above example is working fine for me, but i want to modify the following line to send notification to multiple people (preferably in CC):

```
mail to: 'team@example.com',
```

I'm using Jenkins ver. 2.41

Comment: what the plugin do you use?

Comment: Plugin for what? I have the standard installation of Jenkins ver. 2.41

Answer (score 16):

I don't know if you can CC them, but to send to multiple recipients try using a comma-delimited list:

```
mail to: 'team@example.com,blah@example.com',
```

Comment: According to https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#mail-mail the mail step allows comma separated lists for the parameters 'to', 'cc' and 'bcc'.

Answer (score 6):

Use Snippet generator to explore more options regarding most of the steps. You can `CC` or even `BCC` like:

**Pipeline Command :**

```
mail bcc: 'foo@example.com', body: 'Test CC Pipeline', cc: 'xyz@example.com', from: '', replyTo: '', subject: 'Testing CC', to: 'abc@example.com'
```

Answer (score 6):

For the `emailext` script, use `cc` within `to` section as below:

```
emailext body: 'testing',subject: 'testing', to: 'xyz@example.com,cc:abc@example.com'
```

reference: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issus/JENKINS-6703

Comment: This link is dead. Do you have any way to revive it?

Comment: @Brondahl https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-6703

Comment: for some reason only when putting the cc in "to" it works , thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

For scripted pipeline:

```
mail bcc: '', body: 'Build Report', cc: '', from: '', replyTo: '', subject: 'Build Finished', to: 'example1h@xyz.com,example2@xyz.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had trouble with 'cc:' failing to send out emails. I used the 'to:' line and specified multiple users. You can do this with variables as well, if you have a list of emails you want to pull in. For example, I declared primaryOwnerEmail and secondaryOwners [list of emails] and pulled them in the 'to:' line below.

```
stage ("Notify Developers of Success"){
    env.ForEmailPlugin = env.WORKSPACE
    emailext attachmentsPattern: 'Checkmarx\\Reports\\*.pdf',
     to: "${primaryOwnerEmail},${secondaryOwners}",
     subject: "${env.JOB_NAME} - (${env.BUILD_NUMBER}) Finished Successfuly!",
     body: "Check console output at  ${env.BUILD_URL} to view the results"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For multiple receivers, either you can add them to `to` section or under `cc` section.

For `mail` pipeline syntax, see below ex :

```
mail to: 'user1h@domain.com, user2@domain.com', cc: 'cc1@domain.com, cc2@domain.com', bcc: '', body: 'your_body_content',  from: '', replyTo: '', subject: 'your_subject_line'
```

For `emailext` pipeline syntax, append `cc` within `to` see below:

```
emailext to: '''user1h@domain.com, user2@domain.com, cc:cc1@domain.com, cc:cc2@domain.com''', body: 'your_body_content', from: 'sender@domain.com', subject: 'your_subject_line',
```

Comment: if have the different groups of people that needs to be notified for different SETS of jobs, can you create those as groups or distribution lists and re-use? rather than have to duplicate this in ever job?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your modified pipeline script to send mail notification in cc

```
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
    stage('No-op') {
        steps {
            sh 'ls'
        }
    }
}
post {
    failure {
    mail to: 'team@example.com, cc:xyz@example.com, cc:abc@example.com',
         subject: "Failed Pipeline: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}",
         body: "Something is wrong with ${env.BUILD_URL}"
}
```

}